# Django Login Fails to Redirect, It does not show any error

Tags: django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I'm facing an issue with Django's built-in authentication system. I have a login view in my Django project, but when I submit the login form with valid credentials, the user is not authenticated, and they are not redirected to the dashboard as expected

`HTML`

```
<form class="registration-form" method="POST" action="{% url 'login_view' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="top-form-div">
        <img class="card_image" src="{% static 'images/organizer.svg' %}" alt="Organizer Image">
        <p class="title">Organizer</p>
     </div>

     <div class="form_inputs">
        <input type="text" class="inputs" placeholder="Username / Email" name="username" />
        <input type="password" class="inputs" placeholder="Password" name="password" />
        {{form.errors}}
         <div class="button">
             <input type="submit" value="Login" class="register-link">
         </div>
      </div>
</form>
```

`Views.py`

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.http import HttpResponse, request,  JsonResponse

def loginPage(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
            
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('dashboard')

    return render(request, 'login.html')

def dashboard_view(request):
    return render(request, 'dashboard.html')
```

`urls.py`

```
path('login/', loginPage, name='login_view'),
path('dashboard/', dashboard_view, name='dashboard'),
```

Checked the database to ensure that the user exists and has the correct credentials.

Verified that the input names in the login.html template match the names used in the view function.

Ensured that passwords in the database are correctly hashed using Django's password hashing methods.

Confirmed the correct user model and authentication backend settings in settings.py.

Added {% csrf_token %} template tag inside the login form for CSRF protection.

Checked for any errors in the browser console and Django's development server console, but no errors are displayed.

Comment: Because you are not using a form to clean the raw data coming from `request.POST` I want to ask you to also verify that `print(request.POST.get('password')` is really what you typed into the input field earlier. Please check that for the username too. Also: in case you rewrote the code for `authenticate` in a custom AuthenticationBackend - please post that too.

Comment: Checked and fixed all three things but still it has same behavior, the console prints out exactly what I wrote in the inputs, I have no custom authentications and I also cleaned data using form but still nothing changed @Tarquinius

Comment: Honestly I don't know what's wrong. Since your login-view does nothing "fancy" another option would be to go with the default django login view as displayed [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/auth/default/#using-the-views). Add `path("login_view", auth_views.LoginView.as_view()),` to your path urls and check if it works. If that works we can at least 100% exclude a lot of potential mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

It works if I use admin panel users and not users from my database. To fetch data from my database I used normal ORM instead of built-in authentication.